# mongodb Realm app with sync feature is connecting and disconnecting in a loop because of reading error

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

My app is loading and seems to create a realm, but then it is looping, just connecting and disconnecting with the following message:

````
Connection to daemon was invalidated
Signup successful!
Log in as user: y
Login succeeded!
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = false, async open = false, client reset = falseSync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = false, async open = false, client reset = false
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '13.54.209.90:443' (from '.....:52139')
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Reading failed: End of input
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Connection closed due to error```
````

Connection seems to be established (connected to endpoint), but it then says Realm exists=false!!

Maybe somebody can tell me what could cause the above error and then I can provide more details of my setup.

Comment: Let's stick with asking similar or the same questions just once. Your other question was very similar so you should focus on that one. If more info is needed, update that question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: good point Jay, I went back to work on the first question. I this to connect by updating the  Permissions in Sync according to the Task Tracker app and added the function they added there. Shall I delete this question?